# How to record the selenium rc scripts in pop up window?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

My website is opening in a pop up, so all my website functionality is on the same window. But I am unable to record the Selenium RC scripts, because it doesn't not the pop up window. Please help me, how do I record them?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE doesn't handle those automatically, you have to insert the command manually.

See [this page](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-HowdoIworkwithapopupwindow%3F) for details. Or this question: [How to record popup windows with selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092149/how-to-record-popup-windows-with-selenium-ide)?

---

**EDIT** - Sorry, I misinterpreted your word "record".

Use [`selenium.selectPopUp()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectPopUp%28java.lang.String%29) or a stronger version of the same: [`selenium.selectWindow()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectWindow%28java.lang.String%29).

Both possibly in addition to [selenium.waitForPopUp()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#waitForPopUp%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: NO, I am writing selenium RC code for this, not selenium IDE.

Comment: Thanx buddy for your fast reply, But I am using the same ,but still control is not going on the specific pop up.

Comment: Oh, you could have said that and save us both some time :). Please, post your code + information about what _exactly_ is failing with what message.

Comment: selenium.waitForPopUp("ABC", "30000");
  Thread.sleep(2000L);
  selenium.selectPopUp("");
  selenium.selectWindow("");             
  Thread.sleep(2000L);
  //selenium.getText(locator)
  selenium.select("region", "CS");

Comment: ERROR IS :com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element region not found
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:100)
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:94)
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.select(DefaultSelenium.java:319)
 at dd_tests.P_Report.testReport(P_Report.java:94)

Comment: Here region is nothing but xpath of one dropdown on the target pop up which is put in configured file.