# Selenium - Handling a Popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to record popup windows with selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092149/how-to-record-popup-windows-with-selenium-ide)

I am learning Selenium using the Selenium 2 Testing Tool's Beginner's Guide book. I am on chapter 1 and trying to handle pop ups.

I have this code recorded using IDE. I am using this page - http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/chapter1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/chapter1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=divontheleft</td>
    <td>Assert that this text is on the page</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>xpath=(//div[@id='multiplewindow'])[2]</td>
    <td>2000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>name=popupwindow2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=popuptext</td>
    <td>Text within the pop up window</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=closepopup</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>verifybutton</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, it times out on waitForPopUp. It does not open the pop up at all.

Any help, please?