# Selenium IDE can't find newly opened pop up window

Tags: selenium-ide

My code looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>//div[@id='mainContent']/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/a/img</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>waitForPopUp</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>30000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>selectWindow</td>
  <td>title=UploadWindow</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>id=MainUploadButton</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried countless different techniques including
WaitForPopUp
WaitForFrameToLoad
SelectWindow
SelectPopUp etc.
I've tried to title, name, var (not entirely sure how var works). Also tried blank, and the title bar without (name/title)

Would be awesome with any suggestions how to approach this problem.

Comment: does you pop up window has url in it? Please also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092149/how-to-record-popup-windows-with-selenium-ide for more info.

Comment: @AbdulHameed Yes it does have an url. I read your url before posting but it didn't help me unfortunately.